# image background in another container

Tags: css, image, tabs, tags

I created a slider with tabs. Each tab must contain a corresponding background image. But in my case the image must be in the background of the  element.
When clicking on a tab the image must change
Is it possible to do this?

[image: image example]

```html
        <header class="header">
            <div class="first_slider">
                <div class="tabsy">

                    <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tab" checked>
                    <label class="tabButton" for="tab1"><span class="btn_content">école</span></label>
                    
                    <div class="tab">
                        <div class="content">
                            <img src="./app/img/slider_2.jpg" alt="">
                            <h3>Un printemps robotique à Arts et Métiers</h3>
                            <p>Le campus Arts et Métiers de Lille, se positionne comme un acteur incontournable de la robotique par ses activités de formation, de recherche et de transfert technologique. </p>
                            <a href=""> <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Lire plus</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tab">
                    <label class="tabButton" for="tab2"><span class="btn_content">Robotique</span> </label>
                    
                    <div class="tab">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Heading 2</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
                            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Lire plus</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tab">
                    <label class="tabButton" for="tab3"><span class="btn_content">industrie du futur</span> </label>
                    
                    <div class="tab">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
                            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Lire plus</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second_slider">

            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Can you please describe your targeted result a little bit more in detail please? What exactly do you mean with "background image"? You can set an elements background via CSS for example

Comment: I understand but i want my image fit my header tag not my tabs container! i have updated my image example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still trying to figure out what exactly you mean.
But this is how I interpret it.

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  switch($(this).attr('id'))
  {
   case "tab1":
     $('header').css('background-image', 'url(imagefile1)');
   break;
    case "tab2":
     $('header').css('background-image', 'url(imagefile2)');
   break;
    case "tab3":
     $('header').css('background-image', 'url(imagefile3)');
   break;
  }
});
```

```css
.tab{
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  padding:2px;
}

.header{
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="tab" id="tab1"> TAB 1</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab2"> TAB 2</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab3"> TAB 3</div>
</div>

<header class="header">
  
</header>
```

Comment: I animate tabs slide in CSS